# How to make a polymer element draggable

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to enable **HTML5 drag and drop on a custom polymer element** but it doesn't work. Without polymer it's possible to just add the `draggable` attribute.

Here is my code in Dart:

#### my_component.html

```html
<polymer-element name="my-component">
  <template>
    <style>
      @host {
        :scope {
          display: block;
        }
      }
      div {
        background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      Drag me
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_component.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

#### my_component.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('my-component')
class MyComponent extends PolymerElement {
  MyComponent.created() : super.created();
}
```

#### test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="my_component.html">

    <script type="application/dart">import 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-component draggable="true"></my-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried extending directly from an HTML Element. This didn't work either.

**Any ideas how a polymer element can be made draggable?**

Edit: There is a [Bug Report](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15564) for this.

Comment: http://edu.makery.ch/projects/dart-html5-drag-and-drop/

Comment: As don olmstead [describes here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web/LwOquOXHnwQ/xeRF89yNcp0J) this is working properly in Polymer.js: http://jsbin.com/ejihim/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

I know this is fairly dated, but I'm leaving this here for others who might be looking.  There is a core element in Polymer now for dragging support: https://github.com/Polymer/core-drag-drop.  There is a demo.html file to show you how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just hope they will fix the bug that is preventing shadow dom nodes from working properly with drag and drop: See [this chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264983). I'd really like to do polymer drag and drop with Dart!

Comment: This is also *outdated*, weird how fast tech changes... Core prefixed elements will not work for Polymer 1.0 or 2.0. Refer to [sortablejs](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/), which supports polymer based drag and drop.

Answer (score 2):

**For Polymer 1.0/2.0**

Most answers here tackle try to answer the OP for Polymer v0.5 [*outdated*]. Core prefixed elements will not work for Polymer 1.0 or 2.0.

Refer to [sortablejs](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/), which supports polymer based drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

to make my Polymer elements draggable I used the JS library [Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/), in my case the polymer components were also in a grid, so i used it in combination with [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in Dart, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Polymer Gesture Events](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events) can be used to make a polymer component **draggable**.

1. Inherit Polymer.GestureEventListeners
2. Add track event listener:

`<div id="dragme" on-track="handleTrack"></div>`

A detailed sample is already provided on [Polymer Gesture Events](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events) page.