# How to use core-drag-drop in Dart to make a Polymer Element Draggable?

Tags: drag-and-drop, dart, dart-polymer, dart-html, core-elements

I'm trying to make a Polymer Dart element draggable, and swap info with another item in a list.  My latest attempt is using <core-drag-drop> element.  I'm using the events created by this element of trackstart, track, and trackend.  I can get them to fire, but I'm unable to figure out how to get a visual representation of the drag effect, like you can with regular <div> elements by setting their draggable attribute to true.  Not only that I can't figure out how I'm supposed to get info out of these JS events.  I have managed to get some data from the Dart event, but I'm sure there is some missing data set by the <core-drag-drop> element, (or is there?).

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_drag_drop.html">

<link rel="import" href="draggable-item.html">

<polymer-element name="item-list">
    <template>
        <core-drag-drop></core-drag-drop>
        <draggable-item id="item1" on-trackstart="{{ dragStart }}" on-track="{{ dragIt }}" on-trackend="{{ dragEnd }}"></draggable-item>
        <draggable-item id="item2" on-trackstart="{{ dragStart }}" on-track="{{ dragIt }}" on-trackend="{{ dragEnd }}"></draggable-item>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'dart:html';

      import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

      @CustomTag('item-list')
      class ItemList extends PolymerElement {
        ItemList.created() : super.created();

        ...

        dragStart(Event ev) {
            print("dragStart: ${ev.currentTarget.id}");
        }


        dragIt(Event ev) {
            print("dragIt: ${ev.path}");
        }

        dragStop(Event ev) {
            print("dragStop $ev, ${ev.target.id}, ${ev.path}");

        }
      }
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This works in printing out info, but still leaves me clueless on how I can use this to drag an item over another, highlighting targets as they are dragged over, and then swapping info with the end target.  This is in aid of swapping the order of items in a list.  A bit like the Google Play Music app, where you can drag a song and drop it in a different position in the play queue.  Can someone help me here?

UPDATE (Clarification)
I'm wanting to make a Polymer Dart Element draggable.  The <core-drag-drop> demo.html is for dragging <div> elements.  I can get drag and drop to work on <div> fine in Dart.

Comment: There was a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264983) (fixed recently) but probably not yet landed in a release (especially Dartium). Have you checked if your problem might be caused by this bug?

Comment: I am able to get events fired for this, so I'm not sure what bug you refer to.  However <core-drag-drop> is the only way I've come anywhere near success.  Is the other Drag and Drop events fired in onDragStart and friends what you're talking about?  If it is then I can't get them working in Polymer, so maybe.

Comment: Seems there is a fix on the way https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/pull/102/files#diff-4ac32a78649ca5bdd8e0ba38b7006a1eR5

There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800171

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at the demo pages?

JS:

https://github.com/Polymer/core-drag-drop/blob/master/demo.html

Dart:

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/blob/master/web/core_drag_drop.html

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/blob/master/web/core_drag_drop.dart

Here they define the drag appearance by assigning HTML to the `avatar` field of the `drag-start` event details.

Comment: I was not yet able to access event details directly in the Dart port of core-elements. A unit test I wrote shows how I had to do it https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/test/core_selector_multi.dart#L47
`var detail = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e)['detail'];` for the case you run into that issue too that `event.detail` is always null. It seems to work in the example without this workaround though.

Comment: Actually, having looked at this example again, I realise it's doing drag and drop on <div> elements, not Polymer Elements.  I can get drag and drop to work on <div> elements in a Dart only app, using the onDrag* Events.  It's making a Polymer Element draggable that I'm having the triuble on.

Comment: I've looked at the demo.html example lots of times before I asked the question.  Thanks though.

Comment: It should work the same way with a Polymer element. If it doesn't it's probably the bug linked in my comment to your question.

Comment: I'm struggling with how to use dnd from dart too. Is it really true that we need to be manipulating a JsObject to do this? Surely I'm missing something

Comment: There is an open bug about passing event details between JS and Dart, this causes problems with the core- and paper-elements which are just wrapped JS elements and this makes the workaround using JsObject necessary. The upcoming release seems to have a fix for this.